# Seeking proper system for pairing types

Tags: c++, template, inheritance

My code below ensures that only land animals can be a "representatives" for `Land` while only ocean animals can be representatives for `Ocean`, and so forth for `Air`, `Underground`, etc...  Just want some feedback about whether this system I've come up with is any good or if there is a better one.  Note:  I'm using structs instead of classes to keep it simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct IAnimal { virtual ~IAnimal() = default; };

template <typename T>
struct Animal : virtual IAnimal {};  // Animal<T> can only be pair with T, where T is derived from Place.

struct Place {
    IAnimal* representative;
    virtual bool setRepresentative (IAnimal* a) {
        representative = a;  std::cout << "Done.\n";  return true;
    }
    virtual bool canUse (const IAnimal*) const = 0;
};

template <typename Derived>
struct PlaceCRTP : Place {
    virtual bool setRepresentative (IAnimal* a) override {
        if (canUse(a))
            return Place::setRepresentative(a);
        std::cout << "Cannot be done.\n";
        return false;
    }
    virtual bool canUse (const IAnimal* a) const override {
        return dynamic_cast<const Animal<Derived>*>(a) != nullptr;
    }
};

struct Land : PlaceCRTP<Land> {};
struct Ocean : PlaceCRTP<Ocean> {};

struct Elephant : Animal<Land> {};
struct Moose : Animal<Land> {};
struct Deer : Animal<Land> {};
struct Whale : Animal<Ocean> {};
struct Shark : Animal<Ocean> {};
struct Crab : Animal<Ocean>, Animal<Land> {};  // Note: Crab can represent Ocean or Land!

int main() {
    Land land;
    Elephant elephant;
    Whale whale;
    land.setRepresentative(&elephant);  // Done.
    land.setRepresentative(&whale);  // Cannot be done.

    std::list<IAnimal*> allAnimals, landCandidates;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        allAnimals.push_back (new Elephant);
        allAnimals.push_back (new Whale);
        allAnimals.push_back (new Moose);
        allAnimals.push_back (new Shark);
        allAnimals.push_back (new Crab);
    }
    for (IAnimal* a : allAnimals)
        if (land.canUse(a))
            landCandidates.push_back(a);
    std::cout << allAnimals.size() << std::endl;  // 50
    std::cout << landCandidates.size() << std::endl;  // 30 (10 Elephants, 10 Moose, 10 Crabs)
}
```

One drawback I can think of right away, is that the repeated dynamic casts cost performance, but looking up a map might be slower.

Comment: I have rolled back your revisions to your question. Etiquette here on Code Review suggests two things: Changes you make to your code that are inspired by answers to your quesiton, should be presented for review in a new question ([What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)). Secondly, it is polite to upvote, and accept those answers that most help you with your concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of `Place.canUse(Animal)` suggests that places use animals. 
But in reality it's the other way around.
The question is not if land can use a whale,
but if a whale can "use" land.
I suggest to invert the design to `Animal.canUse(Place)` (or possibly even `canInhabit`).

If performance is important,
then you can add in `Animal` one method for each `Place` type,
for example `canUseLand`, `canUseOcean`.
After all, do you seriously need to consider future expansion of place types?
It's the animal kingdom that's likely to grow.
And the `canUseX` methods only need to be implemented in higher level classes,
the vast majority will be happy to inherit.

Comment: Thanks.  You've inspired me to write another solution using double dispatch instead of CRTP (updated in my question).

Comment: That belongs to another question...